# Update multiple rows with one query php

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a table like this:

```
optionId - optionName    -   optionValue

1          paypalEnv         // empty right now
2          paypalClientId    // empty right now
3          paypalSecret      // empty right now
```

I want to update all the rows with 1 query like this: UPDATE options SET paypalEnv = ?, paypalClientId = ?, paypalSecret = ?

Comment: Have you tried it? UPDATE without a WHERE clause will update all rows.

Comment: @aynber I know I can use the WHERE clause but can I use WHERE clause for multiple Ids?

Comment: If they're all going to be the same value, yes. If not, then I'd suggest the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the following query :

```
UPDATE options SET optionValue  = CASE
    WHEN optionName = 'paypalEnv' THEN value1
    WHEN optionName = 'paypalClientId' THEN value2
    WHEN optionName = 'paypalSecret' THEN value3
    ELSE optionValue
    END
WHERE optionId in (1,2,3)
```

You could also replace the WHERE clause with this one :

```
WHERE optionName in ('paypalEnv','paypalClientId','paypalSecret')
```

Comment: Then you can accept this answer, glad to have helped you, have fun with your queries ;)

Comment: Can I know what this query is called?

Comment: This is a classic update with "case when statement", there is no specific name for such a query

Answer (score 1):

Or, more simply...

```
UPDATE options SET optionValue = 
CASE optionName 
WHEN 'paypalEnv'      THEN value1
WHEN 'paypalClientId' THEN value2
WHEN 'paypalSecret'   THEN value3
ELSE optionValue
END
WHERE optionId in (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY on `(optionId, optionName)`, then you can use IODKU:

```
INSERT INTO options (optionId, optionName, optionValue) VALUES 
  (1, 'paypalEnv', ?)
  (2, 'paypalClientId', ?)
  (3, 'paypalSecret', ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  optionId    = VALUES(optionId),
  optionName  = VALUES(optionName),
  optionValue = VALUES(optionValue)
```

Comment: Good old IODKU.